# Can I display submenus in groups, using wp_list_pages?

Tags: pages, menus, children

Say I have top-level(parentless) pages called **Fruit**, **Animals**, **Cars**.

When, say, **Fruit** is selected I would like to show links to the individual **fruit** pages below. I would like to be able to dislpay these **fruits** (or **animals**, or **cars**) in several groups with a space between each group of fruits.. a bit like this

```
+---------------+-----------+--------+
|   Fruit       |  Animals  |  Cars  |
+---------------+-----------+--------+   
|   Apple       |           |        |
|   Kiwi        |           |        |
|   Watermelon  |           |        |
+---------------+-----------+--------+  
|   Banana      |           |        |
|   Lemon       |           |        |
+---------------+-----------+--------+  
|   Strawberry  |           |        |
|   Raspberry   |           |        |
+---------------+-----------+--------+
```

You can see in this case, I have roughy divided the **fruit** by color, putting a space inbetween. For **cars** or **animals** it might be another criteria. This criteria does not have to be explicitly named anywhere. So I wondering how to output this list, in a way which requires little techinical ability for the person who enters the pages in the backend.

At the moment I do this to output the child pages:

```
if( $post->post_parent )
    $children = wp_list_pages('depth=1&title_li=&child_of='.$post->post_parent.'&echo=0'); 
else
    $children = wp_list_pages('depth=1&title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0');

echo $children;
```

But I can't see a way to limit the output to categories, or something similar, using wp_list_pages. The nearest I can see is the 'authors' option, but it doesn't make much sense to login as different users to create different blocks in the menus...

Comment: Any reason you just don't use the menu system and no `wp_list_pages()`?  The menu system was added for a reason, to make things like this easier.

Comment: the menu system seems like too much work for the non-technical person who will maintain the website. if I did use it, how would i get the gaps i described above?

Comment: ok, i solved this problem by having pages with a blank title (just a few spaces), and placing it using the Order number. This creates a gap in the menu list. It's horribly hacky though

Comment: Please add your solution as answer and mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe choose to use a tree like that:

- Fruits
- - Color1
- - - Apple
- - - Watermelon
- - Color2
- - - Banana
- - - Lemon
- Level1
- - Level2
- - - Level3

This way, you can, in your theme, hide the second level.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you would use the menu system (like Mike suggested) you can set a class to the menu-item that you want to separate.

In your example it would look kinda like:

- Apple
- Kiwi
- Watermelon (class = separate)
- Banana
- Lemon (class = separate)
- Strawberry
- Raspberry

And then you could style the separate class with a bottom-border or bottom-margin or both if you like.

And if your not satisfied with just a simple separater you can add color classes, like green, yellow, red and add them to each and every menu-item. This time you could style every li with a background of that color.

If you can't find the class-item in the menu system, check **screen options** > **Show advanced menu properties** > **CSS Classes**.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a problem with wp_list_pages() being rather limited...

So I created a custom version of that function and published it to my blog @ [codeFX.biz](http://www.codefx.biz/2011/09/custom_wp_list_pages)

Based on this function you can do whatever you want - without being limited at all.